# How to repair warped plates

Tags: repair, replacement-parts

I have some large plates and a boat hull that have warped due to temperature, and I would like to fix them. Is there any way to do so? And if not, is there any way to replace them? I tried contacting LEGO, with no result.

Comment: Could you add pictures of items in question? It might be easier to suggest once picture is available. For example it is not clear which boat hull you are talking about about and how bad is the deformation.

Comment: I could put pictures of them on Youtube, but I don't know how to put pictures on Bricks.

Comment: When you edit the question, there should be a button with the icon of a picture. Please dom't use youtube (for anything, google does a lot of spying on anyone who goes there).